# Cannot Assign to class because it is a method group

Tags: c#, xna

Here is a code snippet:

```
    public Menu(ContentManager Content)
    {
        gameLogic = new GameLogic(Content);
        LoadContent(Content);
    }
```

That is the constructor for my Menu class in a tiny game I'm doing for a school project. I need to reach the GameLogic, so that I can call it to draw and update from Menu, in case my enum gamestate changes from Menu to Game.

However, Visual Studio has a problem with this, giving me the error that "Cannot assing to gameLogic because it is a Method group". It's not wrong, GameLogic is a class, and a class is a group of methods.

My question is simply, how can I reach GameLogic and call on it's methods in the Menu class without having this problem? Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:

Upon request I'll be adding more code, here's a more detailed code snippet:

```
class Menu
{
    GameLogic gameLogic();
    public enum GameState { Menu, Game, HighScore };
    public GameState gameState = GameState.Menu;

    public Menu(ContentManager Content)
    {
        gameLogic = new GameLogic(Content);
        LoadContent(Content);
    }
```

The line which recieves the error is "gameLogic = new GameLogic(Content);"
I added the enum part to show why I need to reach gamelogic, so that I can update the gamelogic or draw it when enum is Game (I'm going to do the same with my HighScoreclass as well, that will show a high score list, so it's good if I get a solution ^^)

Comment: which line the error is and what is `gameLogic` how it is declared?

Comment: The error line is "gameLogic = new GameLogic(Content);
gameLogic is the variable I'm making a bit further up, forgot to add that in here) of the class GameLogic.
It is declared like so: GameLogic gameLogic();

Comment: what is `gameLogic` show its declaration

Comment: The error line is "gameLogic = new GameLogic(Content); gameLogic is the variable I'm making a bit further up, forgot to add that in here) of the class GameLogic. It is declared like so: GameLogic gameLogic();

Comment: Please update your question with declaration shown in comment, so that others can also easily see the full picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GameLogic gameLogic();
```

Variables don't take `()`. When you add parenthesis language consider them as "Methods".
Change it to the following should get rid of the error

```
GameLogic gameLogic;
```

Comment: Thank you, I feel ashamed I didn't get that on my own >.>